# Can't open nautilus in home path

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, 22.04, nautilus

I'm unable to open Nautilus or Nemo in my home directory.

#### Behavior:

They crash immediately upon opening (when the default home path is opened).
However, I can use other paths. For example, `nautilus ~/Application` works.
I can also use `sudo nautilus`.

When I execute the command `nautilus`, the terminal outputs `Segmentation fault`.
When I try to search something in home path (opened in other paths), it crashes.
Additionally, when certain software tries to open Nautilus (such as when importing a config file), it crashes.

#### Attempts:

I tried changing the default file explorer. The main command I used was `xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`. However, it didn't solve the problem.

Then I attempted to debug the core file using `gdb`, even though it was my first time using it.
I searched and found some commands to dump the core file. After many hours of testing, I finally managed to use `gdb` with the core file.

```bash
ulimit -c unlimited
sudo bash -c 'echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid'
sudo bash -c 'echo ~/coredump/core.%e.%p.%t > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern'
gdb nautilus core.pool-org.gnome..19669.1711535247
```

This is the output:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from nautilus...
(No debugging symbols found in nautilus)

warning: Can't open file /memfd:gdk-wayland (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /memfd:wayland-cursor (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing
[New LWP 19685]
[New LWP 19669]
[New LWP 19670]
[New LWP 19683]
[New LWP 19673]
[New LWP 19671]
[New LWP 19675]
[New LWP 19684]
[New LWP 19674]
[New LWP 19682]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
Core was generated by `nautilus'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007a72a8ea2bad in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7a72837fe640 (LWP 19685))]
(gdb)
```

I don't understand the meaning of the error message. I noticed the word `wayland`, so I switched to X and rebooted the computer, but it still didn't work.

Considering the readability of the question, I didn't provide the output of the `bt` command earlier. Here is the additional information:

```bash
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007a72a8ea2bad in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007a72a8ea2fb8 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#8  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007a72a8ea31f3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
```

Comment: There used to be a bug related to recursive symlinks that produced this kind of behavior - I don't know if it ever got fixed. Does your home directory perhaps have such a link?

Comment: @steeldriver on my Arch system, running `ln -s link link` in an empty directory to create a recursive symlink and then opening nautilus (Files version 45.2.1) to that directory works fine.

Comment: @terdon OK thanks - it was just a guess

Comment: @steeldriver and a good one. Some sort of recursive loop seems very likely here. Maybe too many files? Although that should give an error, seems like an obvious thing to test for.

Comment: The debugger message isn't much to go on - you may get additional context by running a [backtrace](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Backtrace.html) using the gdb `bt` command.

Comment: @steeldriver I replied late. I will add the outputs of command `bt`.

Comment: @terdon Unfortunately, many paths cannot be accessed. Some paths under `/home` also result in segmentation faults, but not all of them.Thank you for your suggestion. I might consider trying Arch.

Comment: @VOCALOID don't change operating systems for something like this! In any case, there is no guarantee that it would work, the OS won't change `nautilus`.

Comment: @terdon Alright,but how would you think about the outputs of `bt`? The GNU I/O share object file is 0 version. Is it the reason about crash? I think fix method is here.

Comment: I really don't know, sorry. All I did was look for the bug steeldriver mentioned, then tried it by creating the fail example mentioned in the bug and I saw it works for me. I never use GUI file managers personally, I find them too slow and hard to use compared to the command line for managing files.